# Error while doing unit test - "Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock" - Android

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

I am trying to unit test my presenter and view in android app with the following code :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MovieDetailsPresenterUnitTest {

    @Mock
    NetworkAPI mNetworkAPI;

    @Mock
    NetworkService mNetworkService;

    @Mock
    MovieDetailsContract.View mView;

    @Mock
    MovieDetailsActivity mMovieDetailsActivity;

    private MovieDetailsPresenter mMovieDetailsPresenter;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.mMovieDetailsPresenter = new MovieDetailsPresenter(mNetworkService, mMovieDetailsActivity);
    }

    @Rule
    public final RxSchedulersOverrideRule mOverrideSchedulersRule = new RxSchedulersOverrideRule();


    @Test
    public void testMovieDetailsEmptyResponse() throws Exception {
        MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails();
        when(mNetworkAPI.getMovieDetails("abcd")).thenReturn(Observable.<MovieDetails>just(movieDetails));
        mMovieDetailsPresenter.loadMovieDetails("abcd");
        verify(mMovieDetailsActivity).onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
    }
}
```

But I get this error :

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mMovieDetailsActivity.onSupportNavigateUp();
-> at com.android.sushil.omdbclient.MovieDetailsPresenterUnitTest.testMovieDetailsEmptyResponse(MovieDetailsPresenterUnitTest.java:65)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
mMovieDetailsActivity.onSupportNavigateUp();
-> at com.android.sushil.omdbclient.MovieDetailsPresenterUnitTest.testMovieDetailsEmptyResponse(MovieDetailsPresenterUnitTest.java:65)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.android.sushil.omdbclient.MovieDetailsPresenterUnitTest.testMovieDetailsEmptyResponse(MovieDetailsPresenterUnitTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at com.android.sushil.omdbclient.util.RxSchedulersOverrideRule$3.evaluate(RxSchedulersOverrideRule.java:45)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Looks like `MovieDetails` and `MovieDetailsPresenter` source code is needed to answer this

Answer (score 0):

Your mocks mNetworkAPI and mView are never injected anywhere and hence the stubbing

```
when(mNetworkAPI.getMovieDetails("abcd")).thenReturn(Observable.<MovieDetails>just(movieDetails));
```

will never happen. Since I can't see the source code for MovieDetailsPresenter I am just guessing that this lack of stubbing leads to the logic of the onSupportNavigateUp() method never being called. You need to make sure all your mocks are included in mMovieDetailsPresenter by marking it with @InjectMocks.

```
@InjectMocks
private MovieDetailsPresenter mMovieDetailsPresenter;
```

Although I can't be 100% sure about this until we see the code for more of your classes.